# cordova.plugins undefined for cordova3.1

Tags: android, cordova

i am trying to develop an android application using cordova. for my application, i require the barcode scanner plugin (https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/)

i am unable to add the plugin using CLI, so i downloaded and copied the files, added the plugin via the following:

```
<feature name="BarcodeScanner">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner" />
    </feature>
```

i then added references to the barcodescanner.js and the cordova files in my application. then in my index, i added the following lines of code to read barcode:

```
var scanner = cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner;
                scanner.scan(
                    function(result){
                        alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text 
                        + ". Format: " + result.format
                        + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
                    }, 
                    function(error){
                        alert("Scan failed: " + error);
                    }
                );
            }
```

but i get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'barcodeScanner' of undefined
```

due to that, i think the cordova.plugins is undefined. what may be the issue for this? am i missing anything?

Comment: what's problem with CLI?

Comment: having bigtime issues setting it up on windows.

Comment: i used cli to run it on an iOS device. still am not able to get it up and running

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple project for you and have added barcode scanner plugin through CLI from [github](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git).

> You can download my Project from [here](http://harshgoswami.orgfree.com/bs.rar).

After Downloading, import it and check few things with your project like

- Plugins package name in src folder and its code
- config.xml
- AndroidManifest.xml

Hope this will help you out.